# Setar auto-increment no DBeaver

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, dbeaver

Apos criar a coluna `idpagamentoCielo` como chave primaria, não consegui adicionar propriedade `auto-increment` à coluna.

De que forma posso atribuir a propriedade `auto-increment` à coluna `idpagamentoCielo`?

Obs.: o banco é postgresql

**SQL de geração automatico**:

```
CREATE TABLE public.pagamentocielo (
    idpagamentocielo int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pagamentocielo_pk PRIMARY KEY (idpagamentocielo)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optei por criar o sequence para a colunda

```
INSERT into pagamentocielo values (nextval('idpagamentocielo_seq'),'txtxtxt');
```

Solucionou meu problema